# Извлечь номер версии программы

Tags: delphi

Как извлечь номер версии (в 4 цифры) программы в Delphi и записать в какую-нибудь переменную?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уже нашел, отвечать не стоит.

```
function GetMyVersion:string;
type
  TVerInfo=packed record
    Nevazhno: array[0..47] of byte; // ненужные нам 48 байт
    Minor,Major,Build,Release: word; // а тут версия
  end;
var
  s:TResourceStream;
  v:TVerInfo;
begin
  result:='';
  try
    s:=TResourceStream.Create(HInstance,'#1',RT_VERSION); // достаём ресурс
    if s.Size>0 then begin
      s.Read(v,SizeOf(v)); // читаем нужные нам байты
      result:=IntToStr(v.Major)+'.'+IntToStr(v.Minor)+'.'+ // вот и версия...
              IntToStr(v.Release)+'.'+IntToStr(v.Build);
    end;
  s.Free;
  except; end;
end;
```

Comment: строчку с result лучше писать так
result:=Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [v.Major, v.Minor, v.Release, v.Build]);